# how to align a set of names in alphabetical order using libre office

Tags: libreoffice

I just want to make a list of botanical names and I want them to be aligned in alphabetical order. I know we can do it using Libre office but how?.

Comment: Do you have the list of names already in a file? How does the list look like?

Comment: i am preparing a file which basically has a lot of botanical names of plants present in our text book and as it is very often that we dont find any such trend in text book but i think learning all those alphabetically could be easier

Answer (score 1):

There are two LibreOffice components that fit your needs: **Writer** and **Calc**. Which to choose depends on your knowledge and how you want to use the list.

**You should choose Calc if:**

- the list layout isn't important for you
- assuming you want to print the list out, you don't care a lot about the print layout;

**You should choose Writer if:**

- you're quite familiar with Writer or at least any text processing software;
- you want to put text before and behind the list;
- the file on the screen should look very similar to the result of printing it directly.

With **Calc**, you could simply put all the names into the cells of a spreadsheet column. Sorting the column is very easy. Assuming your list looks like this:

[image]

You could either sort it using menu "Data" -> "Sort"; or you enable the "AutoFilter" (using menu "Data" -> "Filter" -> "AutoFilter"), then you can enable sorting by clicking on the little button in the header cell (in my example: the first cell, with green background):

[image]

With **Writer**, you would have to insert a table into the document first (menu "Table" -> "Insert"), deciding how the table should look like (how much columns and so on). Sorting the table is easy, too (select table, then menu "Table" -> "Sort"), but you will have to do more things manually.

([Link to source for my example data](http://www.abundanthealth4u.com/Common_and_Botanical_Name_Index_s/59.htm))